# How to know if a compiler performs memory alignment or not?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am working on an embedded systems project. My target is 32-bit (32-bit address bus).

I need to know if the compiler performs memory alignment or not.

In other words, if I declared the following variable:

```
uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
```

`x` will be saved in a specific entry like that:

```
Address 0x00000000 -> FFFF0000
```

Or could it be saved like that:

```
Address 0x00000000 -> 000000FF

Address 0x00000001 -> FF000000
```

Comment: 1. What will it give you? 2. Try and see if you have that, if you do you're all set.

Comment: Read the manual of your compiler. Usually compiler provide ways to specify explicit alignment control on statically allocated variables, like `#pragma DATA_ALIGN`.

Comment: Also if you are doing microcontroller programming, you usually have the luxury of a "map file", which shows exactly how everything is allocated and at what address.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, your compiler will always make sensible choices for the target architecture.

In general, it will align data types to "natural" addresses for that data type. It's not going to mis-align a variable so that accessing it causes some fault, or has catastrophic performance.

For your particular case, if `x` is a local variable, it might end up in a register or on the stack, and not on an absolute address known in advance at all. Most platforms have rules for stack alignment which might come into play (i.e. the stack might always be aligned to some power of 2 when coming into a function). If it isn't local automatic, the above will apply i.e. the compiler will align the variable in a natural and "good" way.

Comment: if x is a static or global ?

Comment: If x is static or global (global are anyway static) depends how and where you declared it!

Comment: No matter if it is allocated in `.data`/``.bss` or on the stack, the compiler still has to do the same basic alignment considerations. What this answer is saying is that there may be additional considerations on top of that, depending on how the stack is handled ([more info about stack handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just trust the compiler to do its job... otherwise I suppose you could find out by doing some "hackish" stuff:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
  uintptr_t align = (uintptr_t)&x % sizeof(uint16_t);

  if(align != 0) // aint gonna happen
  {
    printf("Scandal! Variable incorrectly aligned!\n");
  }

  align = (uintptr_t)&x % sizeof(uintptr_t);
  if(align != 0) // might very well happen, not an issue
  {
    printf("Variable not aligned at an address which is a multiple of the CPU alignment\n");
    printf("At address %p, \"optimal\" %p", &x, (uint8_t*)&x - (uint8_t*)align);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

If you are using C11, you can force the compiler to use a different alignment. If you change the above code to

```
_Alignas(uintptr_t) uint16_t x = 0xFFFF;
```

then you shouldn't get anything printed, since it enforces the variable to be allocated at the same alignment as is the address bus width. Why you would want to do this though, I have no idea, as the compiler knows how to do these things far better than the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a simple way to check:

```
uint8_t *pChar;
uint16_t x = 0xFF;
(uint8_t *)pChar = (uint8_t *)&x;
```

and then print:

`*pChar` and `*(pChar + 1)`

It is also helpful to check the Endian mode in your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (probably as a cross-compiler targetting your system), you could use the [`__alignof__` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alignment.html) (it is a GCC extension). You might also want to use the [`packed`  variable attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

As [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) wisely commented, the latest [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard gives you `_Alignof` keyword and [`_Alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) specifier.

<sup>Hence, it is worthwhile to use a *recent* compiler.</sup>

Comment: Or just use a C11 compiler (GCC 4.9.x for example) and then use the standard `_Alignof` keyword.